# I want to provide callback when clients load a javascript bundle library using snippet

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web, code-snippets

my javascript library product is loaded asynchronously through the snippet in the client html.

As follows...

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <script>

    ...

    !function(e,t){function n(e,t){
        ...
        // loads javascript bundle library from server
        ...
    }}(document, window.MYPRD||[]);

    ...

    </script>

    <script>

    // if bundle library is not loaded, the following code will return an error since MYPRD object and myFunc() is not defined.
    MYPRD.myFunc()

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the snippet in that script tag is executed asynchronously and loads the bundle, so a callback function might be needed to ensure order when there are another executable codes in html.

I would also like to know how to guarantee the order from the client html using a load function, but I wish I could solve this issue in my snippet or my JavaScript bundle library.

What should I do? Please explain in detail. (I am a beginner in Javascript and web development.)

Thank you.

Comment: The question is a bit broad. To write maintainable code, you would have one script / part of the script serving as entry point. This part will load and wait for other scripts and resource, and will call the corresponding functions.  To manage your dependencies you could use a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). In your example if you don't use any tool, then you would pass a callback to your function, in your function you call the callback as soon as `MYPRD` is available  and pass `MYPRD` as argument. In the callback you would write `MYPRD.myFunc()`

Comment: you could also use `events`